# Order resets to Processing after Partial Refund

Tags: magento2

We have a custom *Order Status* that has been created for the Warehouse to indicate that an order is currently being prepared:

- Status: **Picking**
- State code and Title: **processing[Picking]**

However, we've noticed that if the Sales team generate a Partial Credit Memo (e.g. one line removed or adjusted down) that the Order resets back to Processing (instead of staying on Picking). If missed, this can result in an order being picked twice.

I was hoping someone might have a solution to this such as a setting that I've missed or some code I can override.

Comment: I've ended up reporting this as a big, which has been acknowledged for development in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I am also in the process of doing this. I have found the code I need to do a rewrite on

vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment.php

there are two functions 
Line 622
public function refund($creditmemo)

Line 716
registerRefundNotification($amount)

I have literally just started on my solution but Hopefully this is a good start for you.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up reporting as a bug. This issue has been around since 1.x days. I'm surprised it hasn't been an issue for many others.

Answer (score 0):

But there is a setting for order state to status relation. The "Picking" status most likely was not assigned to the processing state. So, after operations like a partial refund the order status was falling back to processing.

Assigned "Picking" status to the "processing" state, the "Picking" becomes 'legal' for the "processing" state.

Config:
*Store->Order Status->Assign Order Status to State*